# Netezza Create Table of records that are not in both original tables

Tags: sql, join, distinct, netezza

Hi this might be a simple question but:

I have 2 tables, one of 29million entries, the other of 40million, there is significant overlap. I want to create a third table that only includes records that DO NOT appear in both tables.

Usually to do this I would take a sideways copy of the original table, add a flag for every record that does appear in both using a simple join and update statement and then drop all the records with a flag. However due to the huge number of records involved and the shared nature of my resources, this method is taking too long.

Is there a more direct way to make such a table?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use full join to find differences
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 AS t1
    FULL JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key2
    WHERE t1.key1 IS NULL OR t2.key2 IS NULL

Comment: Works a charm :) Feel free to add that as an answer, I knew there must be a simple solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use full join to find differences

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS t1 
FULL JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key2 
WHERE t1.key1 IS NULL OR t2.key2 IS NULL
```

Comment: This will work as long as the columns you are comparing/joining on don't have NULL values, because a NULL won't join to a NULL. This answer implies that they wouldn't be by calling the column key1, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: I think both could not be NULL. How would the comparison then make sense?

Comment: Seems to work for me, the key columns can't have null values cos theyre unique keys

Comment: In situations where you need to compare the data where one set doesn't have a key (e.g. when populating slowly changing dimensions from source data that has a natural key unrelated to the surrogate key used in the dimension table), you will need to locate the record based on that nat key, and then figure out if any of the other cols are different.  If all you're doing is finding rows in table1 and table2 who have a non-null key column that is not in both, the full join will work. When you have to compare the rest of the row's cols that might be non-null (eg change detection) the method fails.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your comments that you were actually inquiring about finding rows where the *key columns* weren't present in both, rather than what your question seems to pose (where the entire *record* wasn't in both).

If that's the case, then the FULL JOIN approach will work for you, but in case you (or someone else) needs to compare the full record (potentially with NULLs), here's a comparison of the methods I know of.

```
create table tableA (col1 integer, col2 integer);
create table tableB (col1 integer, col2 integer);

insert into tableA values (1,1);
insert into tableB values (1,1);
insert into tableA values (NULL,1);
insert into tableB values (NULL,1);

insert into tableA values (2,2);
insert into tableA values (NULL,2);

insert into tableB values (3,3);
insert into tableB values (NULL,3);

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from tableA order by col1, col2;
 COL1 | COL2
------+------
      |    1
      |    2
    1 |    1
    2 |    2
(4 rows)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from tableB order by col1, col2;
 COL1 | COL2
------+------
      |    1
      |    3
    1 |    1
    3 |    3
(4 rows)
```

In this case the FULL JOIN will include the (NULL,1) tuple and join it even though it is in both tables. This behavior is, of course, due to us relying on NULLs not joining.  When the columns you are comparing can't be NULL, then this approach should work just fine.

```
select A.Col1 A_Col1, A.Col2 A_Col2, B.Col1 B_Col1, B.Col2 B_Col2
from tableA a FULL JOIN tableB b
on a.COL1 = b.COL1 
and a.COL2 = b.COL2
where a.COL1 is null 
or b.COL1 is null;

 A_COL1 | A_COL2 | B_COL1 | B_COL2
--------+--------+--------+--------
        |        |      3 |      3
        |      1 |        |
      2 |      2 |        |
        |      2 |        |
        |        |        |      3
        |        |        |      1
```

A method that will work irrespective of NULL constraints is using EXCEPT. UNION, INTERSECT, and EXCEPT will all treat two NULL columns as matching. This approach also has the advantage of returning the rows in the proper, non-joined shape.

```
(select * from tableA
except 
select * from tableB)
union
(select * from tableB
except 
select * from tableA);

 COL1 | COL2
------+------
      |    2
      |    3
    2 |    2
    3 |    3
(4 rows)
```

One other possibility is to use NOT IN, but only in the right circumstances.  NOT IN in Netezza is expressed as a JOIN, and in the strictest sense, it should fail in a similar was as the FULL JOIN when NULLs are in play. And it does, because it returns the (NULL,1) row.

```
select * from tableA 
where (col1, col2 )not in (select * from tableB)
union 
select * from tableB
where (col1, col2) not in (select * from tableA);

 COL1 | COL2
------+------
      |    1
      |    2
      |    3
    2 |    2
    3 |    3
(5 rows)
```

However, some people prefer a more "intuitive" understanding of NOT IN which would match a NULL to a NULL, and you can (depending on your version) request this behavior (which transforms the query under the covers into a JOIN with "OR ... ISNULL" conditions).

```
set enable_notin_transformation=1;

select * from tableA 
where (col1, col2 )not in (select * from tableB)
union 
select * from tableB
where (col1, col2) not in (select * from tableA);

set enable_notin_transformation=0;


 COL1 | COL2
------+------
      |    2
      |    3
    2 |    2
    3 |    3
(4 rows)
```

Setting enable_notin_transformation will almost certainly make the query run more slowly, but if you need it, it's there.